# Execute python command and shell command (using subprocess) sequentially

Tags: python, subprocess

I am puzzled by the order of execution of python command and shell command (from subprocess).

For example, I've got a simple code:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

command="echo 'test'"
arg=shlex.split(command)

with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("line1\n")
    subprocess.call(arg, stdout=f)
    f.write("line3\n")
```

I expect out.txt to be:

```
line1
test
line3
```

However, the actual out.txt is:

```
test
line1
line3
```

Could somebody explain the reason?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Pythons file object performs some buffering before the output is written to the underlying file descriptor (via the `write()` system call). So `line1` ends up in the buffer but is not yet written to the file. The subprocess inherits the file descriptor which has not yet been written to, writes the line `test`, and then Python writes the `line3` into its buffer and finally flushes `line1` and `line3` to the file descriptor.

To work around this, flush the file before calling the subprocess:

```
f.write("line1\n")
f.flush()
subprocess.call(arg, stdout=f)
f.write("line3\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom. This is really helpful. I will check out the file.flush() stuff.